# url design in django-cms

Tags: python, django, url, menu, django-cms

I am using django-cms to design a site,as of now i had to create a basic home page with a menu bar like `About Us`, `Products`, `Contact Us` etc.,

I had done all the necessary settings of `django` and `django-cms`, activated the admin section and working perfectly.

I have created a `Home Page template` that contains the  `About Us`, `Products`, `Contact Us` and created a page called `aboutus` through django-cms `admin` with a slug `about-us`.

Now i had given that slug `about-us` which is nothing but a url in the anchor tag for `About Us` menu , so when i clicked the link its working fine and redirecting me to the page `aboutus` with the url in the browser as `http://localhost:8080/aboutus`.

but the problem is , when i clicked again on the `aboutus` link its generating the url twice that is like `http://localhost:8080/aboutus/aboutus`, i mean for each and every click, the slug `aboutus` is appending to the url.

Below are my codes

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     .......
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('home.html', gettext('Home')),
    ('aboutus.html', gettext("About Us")),
    ('management_team.html',gettext('Management Team')),
)
.....
....
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

**home.html**

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{% block head %}{% endblock %}</title>
      {% render_block "css" %}
  </head>
  <body>
      {% cms_toolbar %}
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="about-us">About Company Services</a><br />
            <a href="management-team">Our Management Team</a>
        </div>
        <a href="about-us" class="menu aboutus">About Us</a></div>
      {% render_block "js" %}
  </body>
</html>
```

So above is my overall code,in which `home.html` displays a home page with the menu as below
(by using some css styles)

```
   About Us
        About Company Services 
        Our Management Team
```

So when i clicked on the the link  `About Us` the url generating is `http://localhost:8000/about-us/` and immediately when we clicked on `About Company Services` the url generating is `http://localhost:8000/about-us/about-us` and `http://localhost:8000/about-us/about-us/our-management-team/` when clicked on `Our Management Team` immediately . So the url is appending to the previous url instead of appending to the `domain name`.

I have created all the pages by using the created templates from django-cms admin as

```
   Page Name                slug

   About Us                 about-us
   About Company Services   about-us 
   Our Management Team      our-management-team
```

So whats wrong in the above code, why the urls are appending to the previous urls instead of appending to the domain ?

How to create a `childs(About Company Services,Our Management Team )` from the django-cms admin to the `parent(About Us)`

Actually i want  to create two pages`(About Company Services,Our Management Team )` under `About Us` page , how can we achieve this in django-cms admin

Can anyone please let me know the concept of menus in django-cms, i have tried and read the documentation of `django-cms many many many times` but unable to understand the concept of `menus` so approached `SO`

Comment: You've made your question very complicated. What exactly don't you understand with the django-cms menu system? Menus in `django-cms` reflect your page layout in the admin. So if you have two pages "company services" and "management team" nested under a general "about page" then when you render the menu template tag using `{% show_menu ... %}` the generated HTML will mirror that page layout.

Comment: for example {% show_menu 0 0 %} what is 0 and o here what if another 0 added ?

Comment: in {% show_menu 1 100 100 0 % } what is this mean ? what happens when numbers are shuffled the order ? (Actually all these are mentioned in docs but unable to technical words exactly..)

Comment: here is my actual template code http://pastebin.com/tWqm6pry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your page layout in the admin section (`/admin/cms/page`):

```
- Home (level=0)
    - About Us (level=1)
        - About Company Services (level=2)
            - Foo Bar (level=3)
        - Our Management Team (level=2)
    - Some Other Section (level=1)
        - Some Sub Section (level=2)
    - ...
```

When you print `{% show_menu A B C D %}` you are rendering a `ul` menu, where A,B,C & D  are numbers which specify the configuration of the menu.

```
A = Start
B = End
C = Inactive
D = Active
```

So `{% show_menu 1 2 0 100 %}`

- `A=1` means start the navigation at level 1, i.e. excluding `Home` which is level 0
- `B=2` means render the navigation down to level 2, i.e. excluding `Foo Bar`
- `C=0` means that for inactive trails, show 0 levels. So if we are currently on the `About Us` page, we wont see any links in the menu below `Some Other Section` (as this is an inactive trail), but we will still see `About Company...` and `Out Management...` (as this is an active trail)
- `D=100` means that for the currently active trail, show down to 100 levels (this is why we see the `About Company...` and `Our Management` mentioned above)

So the result is:

```
- About Us (level=1)
    - About Company Services (level=2)
    - Our Management Team (level=2)
- Some Other Section (level=1)
```

Comment: Thanks very much thats really helpful explanation... Also means that in my above html code i pasted in the alternate url, there is no need to declare the full fledged html code for the tags ?

Comment: Where is this documented at? Am I failing at finding the docs?

Answer (score 1):

use the {% show_menu %} template tag to render menus. Be sure to read the documentation for that as well.

Comment: Actually as i mentioned above i have read the docs many times but i unable to understand the usage so finally approached SO, can u please add the menu tag sample code to my above html code, so that i can learn it practically, already i had wasted 2 days just because of this ......

Comment: In the admin (cms -> pages) reorder (drag & drop) the pages so they are children of about_us.

Comment: then use the following code:
<div class="main_menu">{% show_menu 0 0 %}</div>
<div class="submenu">{% show_menu 1 100 100 0 %}</div>

Comment: here is my actual template code http://pastebin.com/tWqm6pry can u please point me to the right direction in the above html code ?